# Is it possible to use HTTPS certificates for licensing?

Tags: c++, web-services, qt, https

I am working on an application with multiple clients and a server running various web-services for the clients. To implement licensing I am thinking about using HTTPS as a protocol for the web-services using certificates that are issued by our company. By influencing the expiration date of a certificate for a client we can prevent them from using our software after their license term.

It this possible and does it make sense to you?

---

Additional information: I am planning on using Qt/C++ for the clients, and the Twisted framework for the web-services.

Comment: That means if a client wants a license for 3 yrs they will have to buy a certificate of 3yrs. And is there a possibility that more than one client will be accessing the same web service?

Comment: Yes, multiple clients will be accessing the same web service. Ideally, I would like to use one certificate per client that somehow contains information on the number of clients they are allowed to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. I don't know Twisted well, but you can place an Apache proxy in front of the web service, and have that [handle certificate based authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_howto.html#allclients).

As for the client side, watch [this bug](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-7200). [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) should provide you with an escape route if Qt gives problems.

You'll need to think through the procedures around the CA, to make sure this works operationally: Are your sales and billing departments comfortable with issuing a hard cut-off date to each customer? Will the certificate be issued on purchase order, or payment of invoice?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work, the client can opt to ignore any certificate errors, check out the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback event in System.Net.Security

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback.aspx

Comment: I should have mentioned that the clients are written in C++, and that the web-services will use the Twisted framework.

Comment: Ah sorry, don't know why I assumed c#, thought it was tagged as such (but it wasn't)